# DrawerLayout not working with Android 4.4 & SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean, drawerlayout

Today I had one of those "android" moments again, which left me absolutely clueless.

I have an app which consists of a DrawerLayout, which includes a RelativeLayout as container for a SurfaceView (surfaceViewContainer) and a second ViewGroup (subclass of RelativeLayout) as navigation.

When the app starts, in onCreate I inflate the layout and add a SurfaceView to the surfaceViewContainer.

On a Samsung S2 with 4.1.2 and a S3 with 4.3 everything works fine, I can see the SurfaceView  drawn and I can open and close the drawer, by swipe gesture or home button. Then I tested on Android 4.4 with a Nexus 5 and a Nexus 10, on both devices the drawer will not appear. Even pushing the home button won't do a thing.

Even stranger : I can open the Drawer before adding the SurfaceView, when I do so I can interact with the Drawer even after adding the SurfaceView, even on Android 4.4, so open/close works then.

So my question : Anybody experienced something like this before or has some advice or knows what might have changed from Android 4.3 to 4.4?!

ps: I used DrawerLayout successfully in other apps already, just not with SurfaceView, so I assume the problem lies there.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using implementing onDrawerSlide on the drawerListener of the drawerLayour like this

```
@Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
    {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
        mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
    }
```

Comment: It worked! I have a full screen SurfaceView rendering and the drawer would not animate while sliding in, but this solved it. Thanks!

Comment: `super.onDrawerSlide` can not resolved..other things worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. You did it for me. I was struggling with this issue for last two days. overriding onDrawSlider method nailed it.