# DrawerLayout above a SurfaceView that was set setZOrderOnTop(true)

Tags: android

I have a SurfaceView that should be set with setZOrderOnTop(true) , is it possible to have a DrawerLayout that opens over it. currently the surface draws over the drawer.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation the solution from [DrawerLayout not working with Android 4.4 & SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976149) worked for me:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
{
    mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
    mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
}
```

Inside of your DrawerListener

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open, R.string.close)
{
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                drawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
                drawerLayout.requestLayout();
            }
};
```