# NavigationDrawer height collapses to that of the Toolbar after onPause on some devices

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-navigationview

I have a fairly simple application that has a custom `Toolbar` with a `NavigationDrawer`. Apart from these items I have a `GLSurfaceView` that fills the entire screen. In my `NavigationDrawer` I have a list of cases that can be selected and then data is fetched and rendered in the `GLSurfaceView`.

Everything is working fine, except one thing: When the application is paused and then resumed, the height of the `NavigationView` collapses to that of the `Toolbar`. The `NavigationView` can still be scrolled in that small height and when a case is selected at that point, the `NavigationView`'s height is refreshed and everything goes back to normal. This therefore also happens on rotation of the device.

Note that if the `NavigationView` is *visible* when rotating/pausing the app, the issue *does not* occur.

This issue does not happen on all devices though. Here is a list I have tested on:

Issue appears on:

- Samsung Galaxy S2 Tab: Android 6.0.1
- Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge: Android 6.0.1
- HTC One A9s: Android 6.0
- Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1: Android 5.11

The issue *does not* appear on:

- Sony Xperia XZ: Android 6.0.1
- Huawei Honor 7: Android 5.0.2
- Huawei Nexus P6: Android 7.0

I have tried invalidating all the views in `onPause`, but nothing helps and I cannot figure out where I am doing something wrong.

Other notes:

- `compileSdkVersion = 25`
- `targetSdkVersion = 25`
- Support library version: `25.2.0`
- Build tools version: `25.0.2`
- Gradle plugin version: `2.3.0` / Android Studio 2.3

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- This style is set in AndroidManifest.xml -->
    <style name="DemoTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- To be able to use a custom Toolbar. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/demo_color_main_brand</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/demo_color_extras_darkblue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/demo_color_extras_lightgreen</item>

    </style>

    <style name="DemoActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/demo_color_main_brand</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    </style>

   ...

</resources>
```

**activity_demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/demo_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Wrap Toolbar in AppBarLayout to add shadow below the Toolbar. -->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/demo_appbarlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/demo_toolbar"
                style="@style/DemoActionBarStyle" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/demo_appbarlayout" >

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/fv_coordinatorlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".activities.DemoActivity" >

                <com.my.company.demo.views.DemoGLSurfaceView
                    android:id="@+id/demo_glsurfaceview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/demo_navigationview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/demo_navigationview_header"
        app:menu="@menu/demo_navigationview_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/demo_colors_navigationview"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/demo_colors_navigationview" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**`onCreate` in DemoActivity**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

    // Setup Toolbar.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.demo_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Setup NavigationView.
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.demo_navigationview);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Setup DrawerLayout.
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.demo_drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    // Load demo cases.
    mModuleConfiguration = new ModuleConfiguration(getString(R.string.module_config_url), this);
}
```

Before rotation:

[image]

After rotation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar issue that helped med fix my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22402713/1139324). The gist of it is to implement an extra `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` in the `Activity` and do

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
{
    mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
    mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
}
```

to ensure that the drawer is drawn above the `GLSurfaceView`.

Steps to fix:

1. Implement `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` in the `Activity`.
2. Add both an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and the `Activity` as listeners for the `DrawerLayout`.
3. Implement the above `onDrawerSlide()` method from the `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` interface (`mDrawerLayout` is simply a local reference to the `DrawerLayout`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird error, maybe you should call `close` function of `DrawerLayout`  in `onPause` method of your activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it did not help to add that in `onPause()`. The `DrawerLayout` is always closed when an item is selected in the `NavigationView`. While doing this I realized that if the `NavigationView` is showing when rotating the device it works as expected (no collapse). If it is closed the issue occurs. I added a note on this in the question.